# Using fwrite with char*

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings, fwrite

How would one use fwrite to a file with a char*? If I want to append a char* to the end of a file with a newline after, would something like this be right? If you had a variable like:

```
char* c = "some string";
```

Would it be:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "ab");
fwrite(c, sizeof(char*), sizeof(c), fp);
fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
close(fp);
```

I'm a bit confused about the 2nd fwrite statement. Is it sizeof(char*) or sizeof(char)? Should I also have sizeof(c) or is that incorrect? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` is wrong, it returns the size of the pointer itself, not what it points to, you probably want `strlen(c)` there.

Comment: I am not sure you understand the difference between pointer, array and string. So here is a short clarification: `fwrite` doesn't output a `char *`. It outputs an array of `char`. The purpose of a `char *` is to tell where in memory that array is stored. Or more correctly it holds the address of the first `char` in that array. It is important to note that a `char *` only knows where the array is. It doesn't know how large the array is, or how many elements of the array are "used".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first call of `fwrite` that is incorrect.

```
fwrite(c, sizeof(char*), sizeof(c), fp);
```

It should be written like for example

```
fwrite(c, sizeof( char ), strlen( c ), fp);
```

That is the string literal `"some string"` excluding its terminating zero character is written in the file.

As for this call

```
fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
```

then one character `'\n'` is written in the file fp.

Note: the string literal `"\n"` is internally represented as a character array of two elements `{ '\n', '\0' }`.

The function is declared like

```
size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr,
              size_t size, 
              size_t nmemb,
              FILE * restrict stream);
```

and according to the C Standard (7.21.8.2 The fwrite function)

> 2 The fwrite function writes, from the array pointed to by ptr, up to
> nmemb elements whose size is specified by size, to the stream pointed
> to by stream. For each object, size calls are made to the fputc
> function, taking the values (in order) from an array of unsigned char
> exactly overlaying the object. The file position indicator for the
> stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters
> successfully written. If an error occurs, the resulting value of the
> file position indicator for the stream is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers and comments here tell you what's wrong with the code you posted, but a better solution is to use [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs), which is specifically designed to write out nul-terminated strings:

```
const char* c = "some string";

FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "ab");
fputs (c, fp);
fputs ("\n", fp);
fclose(fp);
```